# C++ - static variable in class that counts instances that have been created won't count up

Tags: c++, class, static

I'm a total beginner in C++ and need some help.

I created a headerfile named *shape.h*, in which is a class named rectangle.
rectangle has a length, width and a static inst_count, which iterates every time the constructor is called.

The problem is - it doesn't ...

**This is *shape.h*:**

```
#ifndef shape_h
#define shape_h

class rectangle
{
    private:
        float length,width;
        static int inst_count;

    public:
        rectangle(float length,float width);
        ~rectangle();
        float get_length();
        float get_width();
        int get_count();
};

int rectangle::inst_count = 0;

rectangle::rectangle(float length,float width)
{
    rectangle::inst_count++;
    rectangle::length = length;
    rectangle::width = width;
}

rectangle::~rectangle()
{
    rectangle::inst_count--;    
}

float rectangle::get_length()
{
    return rectangle::length;
}

float rectangle::get_width()
{
    return rectangle::width;    
}

int rectangle::get_count()
{
    return rectangle::inst_count;   
}

#endif
```

**this is the *main.cpp*:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "shape.h"

int main(void) 
{
    rectangle *rect = new rectangle(3.0,3.0);

    std::cout << rect->get_count();

    return 0;
}
```

**The Output is:**

```
0
```

Why?

Comment: Did you include `shape.h` in more than one place?

Comment: No, the whole project is what I just posted. (Whoops so enter sends immediatly.) So its only included in main.cpp

Comment: Also, cannot reproduce http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d59b2b916fb52913

Comment: You shouldn't define `inst_count` in header. That will result in multiple definitions when you will have more source files

Comment: you also shouldnt call `new` here. Just create an instance like that `auto rect = rectangle(3.0,3.0);`

Comment: @user463035818: The OP is trying to cancel destruction for testing purposes.

Comment: -kubawal: That makes sense, but shouldn't be the reason it acts out, should it?

-StoryTeller: Thats odd ... No matter how often I compile - it won't change

Comment: Could not reproduce. Pull your static variable definition out of the header file. In fact, prefer to have all the definitions in a source file.

Comment: @Sven money says you're running the wrong binary; and you're starting an old version.  I'd suggest you delete all the build output you can find and recompile

Comment: @UKMonkey OH!
That worked! Thank you!
But what does that mean?
When I compile and run, shouldnt that be the same as if I would be rebuilding it? Dont really get the concept there. But thank you!

Comment: @Bathsheba destruction would still be after the `cout`

Comment: @Sven That definitely depends on your IDE (or whatever you use) configuration.

Comment: Aside - you have a new with no delete;  that's a memory leak.  Glad you got things working though!

Comment: you are definitely doing smth wrong. Have a look here: http://rextester.com/OBL93645

Comment: @UKMonkey - You'd be the one to point it out :P

Comment: Oh yea ... forgot delete - Haha. Whoops. Thanks for the hint!

By the way: I just wanted to give huge thanks to everbody that helped. For such an amateur question I got somuch help and tips. You guys are amazing. Thank you.